# How to embed/place my own `cloud-config` to Ubuntu image?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, cloud-init

I would like to add `#cloud-config` (with `runcmd`) content file to my Ubuntu image directly rather than specifying it during instance creation.

This `#cloud-config` need to called only `once` during new instance creation.

What is correct folder location and file name (if needed) for the same?

Example cloud-config:

```
#cloud-config
    runcmd:
    - [ ls, -al ]
```